# Empty column name in first column, how do I set the name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

[image]

For some reason when I did this all_data = all_data.set_index(['Location+Type']) the name 'Location+Type' is now gone. How do I now set the first column of the dataframe to have the name 'Location+Type'?

Comment: `all_data.index.name = 'Location+Type'` helps?

Comment: If it doesn't show the index name after calling `set_index`, there's a bug somewhere or something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `set_index(['Location+Type'])` you no longer have the column `Location+Type` instead, it is now the index of your dataframe therefore when printing, you are not seeing the name. If you wish to recover `Location+Type` as a column, then you need to use:

```
all_data = all_data.reset_index()
```

This will create a new index, while returning the original index (`Location+Type`) to a column. As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) states:

> When we reset the index, the old index is added as a column, and a new sequential index is used: